# Get bundle identifier from plist automatically based on scheme/target using fastlane

Tags: ios, fastlane

I have an Xcode project setup with multiple targets/schemes so that I have several apps under the same codebase.

I created the following testing lane in my Fastfile which runs the "sigh" tool for every one of my apps:

```
lane :testing do
  ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"].each do |scheme_name|
      sigh
  end
end
```

Looking at the fastlane documentation, I see you can define a bundle identifier, which sigh uses. But I need it to automatically grab the current bundle identifier from each target/scheme's plist and use that for sigh. Can this be accomplished?

Something like (psuedo code):

```
bundle_id = get_bundle_id_from_plist
sigh(app_identifier: bundle_id)
```

I tried using this plugin: https://github.com/SiarheiFedartsou/fastlane-plugin-versioning which has a method for getting plist path. I then ran this code:

```
bundle_id = get_info_plist_value(path: get_info_plist_path(target: scheme_name), key: 'CFBundleIdentifier')
puts bundle_id
```

The output is $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER), which actually what is in the plist value, so I'm getting closer. But I need this to return the actual bundle id, not just the variable it points to.

The whole reason for me wanting to use sigh is because each app/target has its own provisioning profiles that I had to manually generate initially because of CarPlay entitlement. I would like it to automatically create new provisioning profiles for each target when they expire.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I do not know of any `fastlane` actions that provide such functionality, but you may be able to build a local [fastlane action](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/Plugins.md#local-actions), or create and share a [fastlane plugin](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/Plugins.md#plugins), that provides the `CFBundleIdentifier` using the [code that updates an info plist using the scheme name](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/update_info_plist.rb#L20) as an example.

This code uses the `xcodeproj` Ruby gem to get the Info.plist file from the Scheme. It then changes plist values and then saves the plist file. You could do something similar except just return the `CFBundleIdentifier` from the plist.

If you don't want to create the plugin, I can create it later on this week as this interests me.

This code should work for you until I get the plugin finished:

```
    # At the top of your Fastfile; you may need to add "gem 'xcodeproj'" to your Gemfile and then do a bundle install
    require 'xcodeproj'

    def product_bundle_id(scheme)
      project = Xcodeproj::Project.open('path/to/your/xcodeproj')
      scheme = project.native_targets.find { |target| target.name == scheme }
      build_configuration = scheme.build_configurations.first
      build_configuration.build_settings['PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER']
    end

    lane :testing do
      ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"].each do |scheme_name|
        sigh(app_identifier: product_bundle_id(scheme_name))
      end
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Please see my updated answer. I was able to return the value, but its returning $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) instead of the actual bundle id.

Comment: You are welcome! I have released the plugin. To install it, run `fastlane add_plugin get_product_bundle_id` from the command line. See https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/Plugins.md for docs.

To call it, `get_product_bundle_id(project_filepath: project_path, scheme: 'Scheme Name')`

Comment: Thanks again man. Do you know how to force sigh to include the CarPlay entitlement (com.apple.developer.playable-content = true) in the provisioning profile it generates when one has expired? It's required for CarPlay functionality in my apps.

Comment: Not off hand; I don't work with sigh as we manage our profiles in-house currently

Comment: All good. Yeah I have over 300+ apps in one Xcode project so that's why was hoping sigh could auto renew expired provisioning profiles, which it can, but also to be able to include that entitlement.

Comment: You may want to open up an issue at the fastlane github repo asking this

Comment: @codeman: I also only get back $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) instead of the actual bundle id. What was the fix for this?

Comment: @brainray Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @codeman did you ever figure out the $(KEY) issue?